# Openlayers Custom Marker

Tags: openlayers, marker

some info: 
I got a main layer (map) which and im drawing lines between points recived from a JSON result with a Linestring.

(issue) 
I followed an example online on how to customize the points i am adding. But this does not work. (Look at the function on the bottom.)

Code:

```
//'listOfPoints' is an array containing all the point objects.

var pointmap = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(listOfPoints);

    var lastpoint = listOfPoints[listOfPoints.length -1];


    var vesselLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(data.bridge_name);

    if (lastpoint != null) {
        var markerLayer = getPOI(lastpoint);
        vesselLayer.addFeatures([pointmap,markerLayer]);
    } else {
        vesselLayer.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(pointmap)]);
    }

// Function for creating a marker and returning it to the caller. 

function getPOI(point) {

//This was also tried without the "Style" property. (Only the externalGraphic line)
var temp_feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        point,
        style: { externalGraphic: '/assets/img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 16,     graphicWidth: 16, graphicXOffset:8, graphicYOffset:8  }
    );    

return temp_feature;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, there's error in temp_feature definition:

```
var temp_feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    point,
    null,
    {
        externalGraphic: '/assets/img/marker.png',
        graphicHeight: 16,
        graphicWidth: 16,
        graphicXOffset:8,
        graphicYOffset:8
    }
);
```

It's useful to read and follow API documentation:
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.OpenLayers.Feature.Vector

OpenLayers.Feature.Vector takes three arguments, geometry, object with attributes (which is null in your case, since you don't have any attributes), and object with style.

I haven't tested that code, there may be other problems, too.

And about general use of JavaScript, there is never such thing as

```
style: { externalGraphic: '/assets/img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 16,     graphicWidth: 16, graphicXOffset:8, graphicYOffset:8  }
```

Object is always defined within brackets:

```
{style: { externalGraphic: '/assets/img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 16,     graphicWidth: 16, graphicXOffset:8, graphicYOffset:8  }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I Actually did have { style: { } } in my script. but i changed it for some reason in the paste. sorry! So the null parameter did the trick! Thank you!