# setting a custom marker file in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map hosted on my GitHub Pages account. My goal is to make the markers on the map display. Currently the image doesn't load because the marker.png file is not hosted properly. Here is my map if you wanna see: https://plutownium.github.io/Breweries-Map/

I've followed a few examples of how to upload a custom marker file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817176/openlayers-custom-marker) and [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html). Didn't work. I don't really know how to use OpenLayers -- I've just copied code and modified it where I can. I added `var size, offset && icon` and the `icon.clone()` lines to my code in an attempt to render a custom marker. But it doesn't work, not even on my localhost. I just get the "image did not load" icon where each of my markers should be.

Here is my code:

```
// breweries is a batch of API requests waiting to resolve
Promise.all(breweries)
                .then(r => {
                    // console.log("R:", r); // an array of arrays
                    breweries = r;
                })
                .then(() => {
                    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
                    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

                    markersList = [];

                    for (let i = 0; i < breweries.length; i++) {
                        const listOfFifty = breweries[i];
                        for (let j = 0; j < listOfFifty.length; j++) {
                            if (
                                listOfFifty[j].longitude !== null &&
                                listOfFifty[j].latitude !== null
                            ) {
                                let point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(
                                    listOfFifty[j].longitude,
                                    listOfFifty[j].latitude
                                ).transform(
                                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                                    map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                                );
                                markersList.push(point);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // upload a new marker image...
                    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21, 25);
                    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);
                    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon("/marker.png", size, offset);

                    var zoom = 6;

                    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
                    map.addLayer(markers);

                    for (let i = 0; i < markersList.length; i++) {
                        markers.addMarker(
                            // set the new marker...
                            new OpenLayers.Marker(markersList[i], icon.clone())
                        );
                    }

                    var testMarker = new OpenLayers.LonLat(
                        -120.2146488,
                        35.905002
                    ).transform(
                        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                    );

                    markers.addMarker(
                        new OpenLayers.Marker(testMarker, icon.clone())
                    );

                    map.setCenter(testMarker, zoom);
                });
```

Comment: What is the full path to marker.png ?

Comment: C:\Users\Roland\dir2_JS\opslevel_two\marker.png

Comment: It works on my localhost but still not on github pages. thanks for trying